# How to Keep Original ip address in all apache requests

Tags: java, apache

I have an apache 2.4.6 in a CentOS where I deploy my frontend. This apache is hosted in one server (server A).

In other server (server B) I have my backend build it in java. When I make a request to my frontend, I can see in my apache log /var/log/httpd/access_log the original remote ip correctly, but when I try to get the original ip in java (server B), I always get the same ip (gateway from the server A)

I tried to load the remoteip module in apache, and added the below config in the /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf file, but doesn't work:
    RemoteIPHeader X-Forwarded-For
    RemoteIPProxiesHeader X-Forwarded-By

When I did this configuration, I tried to get the original remote ip from X-Forwarded-For header, but it doesn't work.

So, the question is, how can I configure my apache server to keep the original ip in all the request that my apache does to the backend.

Hope anyone can help me.
Thank you!

Comment: Use [`mod_proxy_ajp`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_ajp.html), not [`mod_proxy`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html), for forwarding requests from Apache to Tomcat.

Comment: How can I do that? I'm using both of them. If I comment mod_proxy, I got a syntax error using just mod_proxy_ajp

Comment: Is "I got a syntax error" supposed to mean anything to us? --- Try to do some **research**, e.g. find an example online of a mod_proxy_ajp setup.